# Immutable JS - get a value inside a nested map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, redux, immutable.js

I'm using immutableJS, React/Redux and I have this map and I need to get the values of `actions`, so it will be like -> `allRetrospectivesMap` -> `id` -> `current_stage` -> `actions`

[image]

I have this code and it works, but it's super ugly, is there a better way to do it?

```
    class UserActionItems extends Component {
      render() {
        const { retrospectives } = this.props
        const actions = flatten(
          Object.keys(immutableHelpers.toJS(retrospectives))
          .map(key => retrospectives.get(key))
          .map(retro => immutableHelpers.toJS(retro.getIn(['current_stage', 'actions'])))
        ).value()

    return (
       <div> 
          <ActionsList
          actions={actions[0]}
          users={[]}
          />
       </div>
    )
  }
}

    const mapStateToProps = ({ allRetrospectivesMap }) => ({
      retrospectives: allRetrospectivesMap
    })
```

Thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `getIn()` method from immutable js.

```
const id = getId() // you've id from somewhere
const actions= state.getIn(['allRetrospectivesMap', id, 'current_stage', 'actions']); // Note: state is your immutable data.
```

Read more about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/getIn)

Comment: How can I get the id? that's why I'm using the `.map` is there another way?

Comment: Is the `id` part of your data / state?

Comment: Oh, I just did this:     const id = Object.keys(retrospectives)[0]
    const actions= retrospectives.getIn([id, 'current_stage', 'actions']); and It worked! Thank you very much :D

Comment: Oh, sorry :( It didn't work, it did localStorage.clear() and it stop working xD haha. So I only need the first id of the actions, that's why I tried this 
    const id = Object.keys(retrospectives)[0]
    const actions= retrospectives.getIn([id, 'current_stage', 'actions'])  
And the `retrospectives` I'm passing it as a props:
    const mapStateToProps = ({ allRetrospectivesMap }) => ({
      retrospectives: allRetrospectivesMap
    }) 
Sorry I'm new on redux, do you know what's wrong?